# How i can handle java command-line arguments?

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-arguments

I'm coding a tool in java that need some input passed by args[]
I know how to use argument but i wish to handle better this input.

this is a part of my code:

```
if (args.length > 0 ) {

        switch (args[0]) {

        case "scan": blah blah
        break;
        case "some cases": some code
        break;
```

but of course args are strictly bounded to their position, in fact in the command line i have to call:

> java javaProgram arg1 arg2 arg3

i really don't like this...

What i want is to better manage this arguments with options like any other c programmed tool, indipendent from positions:

example:

> java javaProgram -ip 127.0.0.1 -database data.txt -vv -out output.txt

any help will be appreciated!

Dave

(i'm thinking about an array list of arguments, can be a solution?)

Answer (score 7):

Use [Apache Commons CLI Builder](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/cli2/manual/index.html) .

Comment: yes but any good guide? it is very interesting!

Comment: I've had some good results from [JSAP](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/) as well, but it seems outdated one person lib - that said, it does work and is kind of object-orientated. You could use it if CLI builder does not suit your needs.

Comment: The cool thing about CLI Builder is the "fluent api" syntax.